# Determine if S = $\{[a,b] | a, b \in \mathbb Q\}$ is a field under $+$ and $\cdot$ Finding multiplicative inverse help

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Determine if S = $\{[a,b] | a, b \in \mathbb Q\}$ is a field under operations $+$ and $\cdot$ where $+$ is given by $[a_1, b_1] + [a_2 + b_2] = [a_1 + a_2, b_1+b_2]$ and $\cdot$ is given by $[a_1, b_1] \cdot [a_2, b_2] = [a_1a_2 - b_1b_2, a_1b_2 + b_1a_2], a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb Q$

---

Clearly closed under addition and multiplication

Since the components are $\in \mathbb Q$ then associative, commutative, and destributive laws follow.

additive identity: $[0,0]$

$[a_1, b_1] + [0,0] = [a_1, b_1]$, holds

multiplicative identity: $[1,0]$

$[a_1, b_1]\cdot[1,0] = [a_1, b_1]$, holds

additive inverse: $[-a_1, -b_1]$

$[a_1, b_1]+[-a_1, -b_1] = [0, 0]$, holds

multiplicative inverse: ??

Unsure how to do this part. I think I have to do this:

$$[a_1, b_1] \cdot [x, y] = [1, 0]$$

Not sure how to though.

Comment: Does $[a,b]$ mean closed interval? Also, your definition of $+$ is garbled.

Comment: What do you mean? I put a line between the question and my attempt at it.  I'm just trying to satisfy the properties for a field.

Comment: By $[a,b]$ do you mean a closed interval from analysis, i.e., something like $[a,b]=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a\leq x\leq b\},$ or do you mean an ordered pair of numbers, usually denoted $(a,b)$ (though, admittedly, this notation is also used to mean "open interval" in analysis)?

Comment: I'm not really sure, the question never labeled it.

Comment: Then where do you find this question?

Comment: A exercise question in class. My prof found it

Comment: Then how does the professor define the symbols?

Comment: There was a typo on my $+$ in the given question that I just fixed. And + and $\cdot$ just means addition and multiplication?

Comment: I think, here $[a,b]$ means ordered pair. In that case it is a field, (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. If this is true, then think $[a,b]$ as a complex number $a+ib$, and then try. You can easily findout the inverse in this way.

Comment: Answer is $$[a_1, b_1]^{-1} = \left[ \frac{a_1}{a_1^{2} + b_1^{2}}, \frac{-b_1}{a_1^2 + b_1^2}\right]$$ No idea how they got that

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's intervals, ordered pairs or anything else, so long as they are items that are distinctly determined by two values. (Which intervals aren't). The operations are defined by the ordered pairs of numbers so they are equivalent structures. Might as well assume they are ordered pairs.

Comment: @Tinler Expand the expression $[a,b]\cdot [x,y]=[1,0]$. You will get two equations in two unknowns. You have to solve those.

Comment: ax + by = [1, 0], I forgot how to do this

Comment: You *don't* get ax+by=[1,0].  You get [ax-by,ax,by]=[1,0] which is nothing more or less than $ax-by=1$ and $ax+by=0$.  2 equations 2 unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve $[a,b]*[x,y]=[ax-by,bx+ay]=[1,0] $

So solve $ax-by=1$

$bx+ay=0$

$bx=-ay $ so (assuming  $b\ne 0$) $x=-\frac aby $

So $-\frac {a^2}by -by=1$ and $y=\frac -1 {\frac {a^2}b-b} =-\frac b {a^2-b^2} $.

And $x=-\frac ab*-\frac b {a^2-b^2}=\frac a {a^2-b^2} $

So $[a,b]^{-1}=[\frac a {a^2-b^2},-\frac b {a^2-b^2}] $

That should look very familiar.

===

If $b=0$ we get $ax=1$ and $ay=0$

And assuming $a\ne 0$ we get $x =\frac 1a =\frac a {a^2-b^2} $, and $y=0=-\frac b {a^2-b^2} $.

So the inverse formula still holds.

===

If $a=0,b=0$ then $[a,b] $ is the additive identity and can not have an inverse.

And indeed $[0,0]*[x,y]=[0,0]\ne [1,0] $